# Combine libstdc++ and other functions into one library

Tags: c++, libstdc++

What I am trying to do is to have a dynamic library (lib_utils.so) that links libstdc++ statically and includes also other utility functions (created by me).
Then I want other binaries to use this library instead of libstdc++.

Seems stupid but I cannot deploy both lib_utils.so and libstdc++.so.6 to my customers and I try to combine them into one single library. I also want to avoid static linking with libstdc++ because I have 5 binaries that need libstdc++.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Why not follow the obvious approach of just wrapping *your* utilities into a library and let the user link with your utilities and the standard library? There's no reason why you'd need to wrap it with libstdc++. Note that, by default, the standard library is not statically linked

Comment: The user does not use my library, only I use these libraries. The problem is that the user does not have libstdc++ on his device and I have to provide it (so my project works), one way or another but I have a restriction for the number of deployed files, that's why I want to deploy lib_utils.so and libstdc++.so in a single library.

Comment: Of course I know the obvious approach, but I want to trick it somehow(because of restrictions), that's why I asked this question.:-). My question is if it can be done or not.

Comment: Out of interest, how is the file count limit explained?

Comment: What's your target architecture? Is it ELF?

Comment: Yes, I would need this on Linux, FreeBSD and OpenBSD. I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wl,-whole-archive /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libstdc++.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -shared -fPIC lib.cpp -o libviata.so
```

Then I loaded this library into a simple app and this app does not require libstdc++ anymore, cause it loads my custom library (which is quite big now, 2.1MB)

```
g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test -L/home/tawfic/Desktop/test -lviata && ldd test
```